# Properties in Delphi 2006 and 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

TEdit looks like this in dfm of Delphi 2006 code.

```
object myEdit: TEdit
   AlignWithMargins = True
   Left = 15
   Top = 25
   Width = 50
   Height = 20
   Margins.Left = 20
   Margins.Top = 30
   Margins.Bottom = 16
   Align = alLeft
   Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
   ExplicitWidth = 100
   ExplicitHeight = 32
end
```

But some properties (like `AlignWithMargins`, `Margins`, `Align`, `ExplicitWidth`, `ExplicitHeight`) are not there in Delphi 7. What are the equivalent properties in Delphi 7 and above versions?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have to remove all these properties from dfm file which makes the UI distorted. I want to retain the UI.

Comment: You are porting from D2006 to D7?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I don't have Delphi 2006, but Delphi 7. So, I have to run this application on Delphi 7. Porting is not my intention.

Comment: Porting is what you are doing. I can see why. Write a Python script (say) to strip out these properties. You'll need to read the margins though and adjust the control position accordingly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - okay, David. I am doing the same.

Comment: @Meraqp I'm afraid you will have lots of problems with trying to retain the UI. You see the main reason why these missing properties were added in later Delphi versions is to much easier way for components to scale properly when form is resized. In Delphi 7 you might be forced to write bunch of code to maintain same scaling functionality of your program. So you should seriously consider of either upgrading to newer version of Delphi or try porting your program to Lazarus (http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) instead.

Comment: There are 3rd party tools available for removing newer properties from a DFM when it has to be used in an earlier version. Such as [Maxidix DFM Converter](http://www.maxidix.com/products/delphi-dfm-converter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi 7 doesn't have those properties, nor equivalent ones, because Delphi 7 was released before Delphi 2006.

- Delphi 7 was released in 2002
- Delphi 8 - released in 2003
- Delphi 2005 - released in 2004
- Delphi 2006 - released in 2005

[Delphi programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_%28programming_language%29)

If you want to port code from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 7, you will have to delete all those properties from your `.dfm` files.